# Would this be considered bad programming practice?

Tags: c++

I had a situation where I wanted to use a default paramenter for a reference in a VERY large legacy codebase for a fix.

```
static bool _defaultValue = false;
bool SomeFunction(const SomeComplexObject& iObj, bool& isSomeVal = _defaultValue )
{
        // ... code
}
```

My issue is with using a static variable inside a namespace just dangling there by itself.

This code is going to be reviewed before being shipped but I'm unsure if it would be considered bad practice to have a dangling static variable like that.

Without the variable you can't have a default value for a reference.  My options are very limited to make other changes to get the desired effect.

Would this be considered "hacky unprofessional coding"?

Comment: This question is more suitable in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) based on what you're asking. voting for closure as opinion-based.

Comment: @codekaizer apologies wasnt aware there was a code review forum

Comment: @Carcigenicate it does have a descriptive name, we're required by company policy to obscure anything we post online

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

1. Remove the global variable.
2. Don't use a default value for the reference argument.
3. Create a function overload that has only one argument.
4. Call the first function from the second function.

---

```
bool SomeFunction(const SomeComplexObject& iObj, bool& isSomeVal)
{
   // ... code
}

bool SomeFunction(const SomeComplexObject& iObj)
{
   bool dummy;
   return SomeFunction(iObj, dummy);
}
```

Client code can call whichever function is appropriate in their context.

Comment: This is pretty good, didnt think of that.  Thanks

Comment: @solarflare, you're welcome.